# How is Geo Stationary Rocket placed exactly above the Location after Launch

Tags: orbital-motion, rocket-science, satellites

[image]My Question is bit deeper on the Satellite been put into orbit of GEO . 
Recently ISRO Launch GSLV Mark 3 to put into GSO . 
After the Rocket is launched and reached the Perigee ( 190 km ) the parameters looked this way .

The Range of 4,500 Kilometre traveled in 985 Seconds by the Rocket. Where as Earth travelled 500 km IN 985 Seconds . So, the rocket had moved 4000 km away from the point of Launch.

After that, the orbit change maneuver and all happen. So It would be really great if someone explains how the satellite is placed exactly above the point of Lauch ( Calling it Geo Stationary ).

Regards,
Sudhir Reddy Nusi .

Answer (score 0):

When a geostationary satellite is launched, the rocket takes it to a GTO (geostationary transfer orbit), an elliptical orbit with perigee (lowest point) just above the atmosphere and apogee (highest) at ~35000km. The satellite itself has a very small thruster which, over several orbits, fires prograde at every apogee until the orbit is circular.

As for how it gets in the correct spot, it's all done by a computer simulating the future and figuring out what it needs to do. While it's still raising its orbit, it will be orbiting much faster than Earth is rotating. It doesn't sit on the target longitude to stay until the orbital period is 24 hours.

Staying in a lower orbit longer will move the predicted longitude eastward, and raising it faster will move it westward.

Comment: Please tell me if this wasn't clear somewhere.